# db.changeVersion doesn't work as expected

Tags: application-development, ubuntu-touch, qt, ubuntu-sdk

I'm trying to upgrade a DB in an app. I use QtQuick.LocalStorage 2.0.

When I call `db.changeVersion` it works, but `db.version` doesn't change until app restarts.

```
db.changeVersion(db.version, "2", function(tx){...}); // Update database to version 2
console.log(db.version); //Should return "2", instead returns previous version of database
```

How can have the new `db.version` without restart the app?

Comment: And this is concerning Ubuntu? I see the ubuntu-touch tag, but I think this is better in [so].

Comment: Sure it is. This is an Ubuntu SDK question. That the answer might also be relevant on other platforms does not mean it should not be asked about the Ubuntu SDK.

Comment: @WebbyIT from what you are saying, my understanding is that `db.changeVersion` is working as expected (i.e. the function documentation does not say that the database version gets updated). Is your callback not doing the version update? I think it might be useful to post what your function is doing to find out what's going on.

Comment: @David Planella well, db.changeVersion changes db.version (that is in the .ini file) only when the app is closed, so you can't use more than one db.changeVersion for session of the app. If you have more than one version of the app (e.g 1.0, 2.0, 3.0) and you want to write db.changeVersion to update to last version, you have to do a function where you can choose if you start from v1.0 or 2.0. To avoid to have a lot of change to do for every new version, I have elaborate this code: https://code.launchpad.net/~rpadovani/ubuntu-calculator-app/dbupgrade/+merge/179023

Comment: @WebbyIT, ah, gotcha. You might want to add the code snippet as the answer, so that others can benefit from it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I resolved my problem writing this function, that permits to upgrade from any version of the DB to the last version without problems.

```
/* We need this function because db.version is in the .ini file, that is update only by Javascript Garbage Collection.
 * So, we have to upgrade from actual version to the last version using only once db.changeVersion.
 * To avoid to have a lot of switch and spaghetti-code, this function allow to add new db version without modify old sql
 *
 * IMPORTANT: NUMBER OF VERSION HAVE TO BE INT (e.g. 0.1, not 0.1.1)
 */
function upgradeDB() {
    // This is the array with all the sql code, insert your update at the last
    var sqlcode = [
        'CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS Calculations(id INTEGER PRIMARY KEY, calc TEXT)',
        'ALTER TABLE Calculations ADD insertDate INTEGER NOT NULL DEFAULT 0'
    ]

    // This is the last version of the DB, remember to update when you insert a new version
    var lastVersion = "0.2";

    // Hack for change old numeration with new one
    if (db.version == "0.1.1") {
        db.changeVersion("0.1.1", "0.2");
        console.log("Fixed DB!");
    }

    // So, let's start the version change...
    db.changeVersion(db.version, lastVersion,
        function(tx) {
            if (db.version < 0.1) {
                tx.executeSql(sqlcode[0]);
                console.log('Database upgraded to 0.1');
            }
            if (db.version < 0.2) {
                tx.executeSql(sqlcode[1]);
                console.log('Database upgraded to 0.2');
            }

            /* This is the structure of the update:
             * n is the number of version that sql update to
             * m is the number of the sql element in the array. Remember that the number of the first element of array is 0 ;)
            if (db.version < n) {
                tx.executeSql(sqlcode[m]);
                console.log('Database upgraded to n');
            }
            */
        }); // Finish db.changeVersion
}
```